# In neural Networks back propagation, how to get differential equations?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am confused why `dz=da*g'(z)`?
as we all know, in forward propagation,`a=g(z)`,after taking the derivative of `z`, I can get `da/dz=g'(z)`,so `dz=da*1/g'(z)`?
Thanks!!

Comment: It depends on what function you are using at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, in many courses, representations like `dZ` are a shorter way of writing `dJ/dZ` and and so on. All derivatives are of the cost with respect to various parameters, activations and weighted sums etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Differential equations come up based on the last layer and then you can build them backwards, the equation as per your last layer can be based on few of the activation functions.

**Linear** g'(z) = 1 or 1D of 1 vector based on layer dimensions

**Sigmoid** g'(z) = g(z)*(1-g(z))

**Tanh** g'(z) = 1 - thanh^2(z)

**Relu** = 1 if g(z)>0 or else 0

**Leaky Relu** = 1 if g(z)>0  and whatever leaky relu slope you kept otherwise.

From there you basically have to compute partial gradients for the the previous layers. Check out http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html for a deeper understanding